# Como fazer um botão ser clicável após determinado tempo em hover?

Tags: javascript, button, css-hover

Para o botão poder ser clicado o usuário precisa ficar com o mouse em cima dele por 2 segundos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solução

Como o botão desativado não consegue registrar o evento, deixei o botão ativo mais com a aparência de um botão desativado com css.

```
.disabled{
  color: grey;
}
```

Para evitar que o evento clique seja acionado utilizo uma flag, se ela for verdadeira ela libera o click do botão, se não retorna false, evitando assim o clique.

```
b.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(!botaoAtivo) return false;
  alert("O botão esta funcionando!");
});
```

Se o usuário passar o mouse em cima do botão, começa uma contagem de 2 segundos, ao passar este período, é alterado o texto do botão e removido o estilo que deixa o botão com aparência de desativado e por fim é setado a flag para informar que o botão esta disponível.

```
b.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  executaFuncao = setTimeout(function(){    
    b.removeAttribute("class");
    b.innerHTML = "Botão liberado!";
    botaoAtivo = true;
  }, 2000)
});
```

Caso o usuário saia com o cursor antes dos dois segundo a função é cancelada.

```
b.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  clearTimeout(executaFuncao);
});
```

## Resultado

O código esta comentário para melhor entendimento da solução.

```js
//Seleciono o botão
var b = document.querySelector("button");

//Criei um flag para saber se o botão esta liberado
var botaoAtivo = false;

//Variável o timeout
var executaFuncao;

//Se o mouse passa no botão ele inicia a contagem e libera o botão ao final dos 2 segundos e altera o seu texto
b.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  executaFuncao = setTimeout(function(){    
    b.removeAttribute("class");
    b.innerHTML = "Botão liberado!";
    botaoAtivo = true;
  }, 2000)
});

//Caso o usuário remova o mouse antes do termino dos 2 segundo a função para liberar o botão e cancelada
b.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  clearTimeout(executaFuncao);
});

//Bloqueia o click caso o botão não esteja liberado
b.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(!botaoAtivo) return false;
  alert("O botão esta funcionando!");
});
```

```css
.disabled{
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<button class="disabled">Coloque o mouse por 2 segundos aqui</button>
```